# ¿Como hacer aparecer un popover con Jquery luego de una condición?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un modal con un botón guardar.

```html
<button type="button" class="guardar btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
```

En caso de que se cumpla la condición, este botón hace el insert de algunos datos en la base de datos. Pero en caso de que no se cumpla (entra al else), quiero que aparezca un popover con una advertencia.

```javascript
if(importe <= debe){
   ..\se inserta el pago en la BD
}else{
..\popover con la advertencia: "El importe ingresado es mayor al debe!"
}
```

¿Cuál es la mejor forma de hacerlo?

En mi caso decidí hacer lo siguiente:

```javascript
if(importe <= debe){
   ..\se inserta el pago en la BD
}else{
   $('#modal-pago .modal-footer .guardar').popover();
}
```

y el button lo cambie a un:

```html
<a type="button" class="guardar btn btn-primary text-white" data-toggle="popover" title="Atención!" data-content="El importe ingresado es muy alto">Guardar</a>
```

El problema aquí es que la primera vez que doy click al botón el popover no aparece, si la segunda vez. Aclaro que, en el código también tengo un `console.log()` y este si funciona al primer click.

Answer (score 1):

Creería que la mejor forma seria manejando el evento del popover de forma manual, pasandole el atributo ***data-trigger="manual"*** y manejando la logica dentro de el evento del click.

Aquí puedes encontrar una explicación mas detallada y con un ejemplo practico
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558232/bootstrap-popover-prevent-show-in-particular-condition#answer-42559061